# How can I point my site from my domain to another host?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, transfer

I have websites running in a host & domain with the same company (CompanyA)
Then I transferred some of my website (www.abc.com) to another domain company (CompanyB)

My problem is www.abc.com can't able to read my index.html.
Always Under Construction.

What are the possibilities that causes for displaying the UndeerConstruction default ng site ng CompanyB instead of my index.html?

Answer (score 1):

We need more info: what do you mean by "some of my website"? This is a strange statement. Have you changed nameservers or IP to point to companyB?

When you transfer a website you transfer the files first then change the nameservers to the new server, this is called mirroring. Then as it takes 48 hours for the dns change to take effect no one is seeing the site as down although there are always some minor problems even if you do mirror the site on both servers. If you haven't changed the nameservers the domain points to then this will be your cause. If you have I will update my answer.

Update after comment:

Actually if your files are on the server with company A then they are still hosting your website and your A records need to point to their server's IP. But this makes the new host (Company B) redundant.

Comment: websiteA websiteB are hosted & domain with CompanyA. then i transfer the websiteB to CompanyB but the websiteB's files are still reside in the CompanyA. I think just need to point from CompanyB to CompanyA. But I am newbie to that.Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Update after comment: response --- after i successfully done with DNS settings. Do I need some time to be reflected?

Comment: domain control panel where it is registered.. means the Company A?.... IP of the new server.. means the CompanyB?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to interpret your question: the first is that you want you domain A to be redirected to the server of domain B. That can be solved be adjusting the DNS-settings.
For instance: www A 123.123.123.123 becomes www A 313.123.123.123. You can look it up on google if you want.

The second way to interpret your question is that you want to tunnel your domain A's viewer to the content on domain B. That should be able with some php scripting. I can't help you with PHP; once again google (next to stack overflow :D) is your best friend.

Comment: i am thinking of just a settings in the CompanyB part. please refer my comment with Liam's answer. Guidance on the right direction is apprecaited.

Comment: You can't do anything without access to the domain's settings, or the original host CompanyA. Otherwise I could show anyone else's website on my server

Answer (score 0):

It must be a different setting in your server configuration file. Can you access www.abc.com/index.html ? If you can you should try adding this in your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: the site is cannot be found,.. even I entered the complete url to index.html or other file

Comment: when did you transfered your website? you must wait 48 hours for finishing succesfully the transfer as Liam said